# Adding a package installed via apt to pip

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, pip

I am trying to install vtk on my Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine with python 3.8.10. I had the same problem as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754702/setting-up-vtk-with-python3-8-and-ubuntu-20-04) and I managed to install vtk via `sudo apt-get install python3-vtk7` . Now python recognizes this installation and I can `import vtk` in a command line in python. However, pip does not recognize this installation and when installing packages that depend on vtk, I get an error message.

How do I add the apt-installed vtk to the list of pip's recognized packages?